# In Vercel, Can I control max serverless function count created?

Tags: next.js, mariadb, serverless, vercel

In Vercel document [functions-created-per-deployment](https://vercel.com/docs/functions/serverless-functions/runtimes#functions-created-per-deployment), max serverless functions count limited 12.

Problem is I built my nextjs project's backend DB with mariadb which has pool limitation  30.(AWS RDS limit)
Each serverless functions create db pool and even if I limit pool size to 1 to project env, default db pool fill to 12.

If I create preview deployment build and admin page, DB pool limitation exceed(12 * 3 = 36).
How can I solve this. I think the best solution is sharing DB pool per deployment and second is serverless function limitation control per deployment.

Here is my sample code.

```js
// src/db/db.js
const mariadb = require('mariadb');
let pool
pool = mariadb.createPool({
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASS,
    port: process.env.DB_PORT,
    connectionLimit: process.env.DB_POOL_LIMIT,
    database: 'MyDB',
  });
export default pool
```

```js
// src/db/user.js
import pool from "@/db/db";
export async function selectUsers() {
  await pool.getConnection()
  return await conn.query(`select * from Users`)
}
```